# JPA query without on

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa-2.0

I try to convert this query in jpa
My sql native query.

```
SELECT *
FROM  tripinfo ti
inner join car c on ti.carid = c.id
left join customerdetail cd on ti.customerid = cd.id
left join station s on ti.fromstxid = s.id
where ti.starttime is null or ti.stoptime is null
```

My jpa query

```
SELECT ti
FROM TripInfo ti
join ti.car
left join CustomerDetail cd on ti.customer.customerDetail.id = cd.id
left join Station st on ti.fromstxid = st.id
```

on command don't seem to exist in jpa 2.0.

TripInfo class

```
public class tripInfo{
 Long id

 @OneToOne  
 JoinColumn(name = "customerId") //can be null 
 Customer customer;  

 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "carid")  
 Car car;

 @Column(name = "tostxid")  //can be null
 Long toStxId;

 @Column(name = "fromstxid")  //can be null
 Long fromStxId;

 @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })  
 @JoinColumn(name = "fromdp")  
 DP fromDP;

}
```

Customer class

```
public class Customer {
  Long id  
  @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })  
  @JoinColumn(name = "customerDetail_customerid")  
  CustomerDetail customerDetail;
}
```

DP class

```
public class DP {
  @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinColumn(name = "stationFrom")
  Station stationFrom;
}
```

any idea to bypass the on command?

Answer (score 2):

Explicit 'On' for joins are not allowed in JPA query, instead they are defined by the relationships defined in Entity.  In your example to get customer details, you can do as shown below.

```
SELECT ti
join ti.car
FROM TripInfo ti
left join ti.customer.customerDetail
```

However, I do not see any relationship defined for station Class. if you have Station Class, then,

```
 @Column(name = "fromstxid")  //can be null
 Long fromStxId;
```

Should be,

```
@Column(name = "fromstxid")
@JoinColumn(name = "id") //Id in Station
Station station;
```

And JPA Query would be,

```
SELECT ti
join ti.car
FROM TripInfo ti
left join ti.customer.customerDetail
left join ti.station
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i added the reference it pass by another class

Comment: SELECT ti
FROM TripInfo ti
join ti.car tc
left join ti.customer.customerDetail cd
left join ti.fromDP.stationFrom st